# How to import xcode project into xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I downloaded SwiffCore (https://github.com/musictheory/SwiffCore) for iOS and the Demo project contains a the main SwiffCore xcode project inside with all the necessary libraries.

Now I want to use SwiffCore in my project.

How do I import the xcode project inside my project?

I tried by dragging inside but it does not copy all files.

I have seen it a lot in other xcode samples.

Regards
mirza

Comment: If you have multiple independent projects and you want to keep them that way but still have some dependencies between them then its best to use Xcode workspaces. There are lot of posts here on SO & else where about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see on the github repository, you just need to drag the Source folder into your project and then use  the classes as indicated by the documentation.